# Using custom wordpress url link parameter instead of GET value in url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

I will keep this very short.

**I've read some tutorials about changing the following url for Wordpress:**

> localhost/mysite/werkvorm?item=test

**To:**

> localhost/mysite/werkvorm/test

So I can get clean links for search engines. And the page loads like its just reading the values of the `$_GET['item']` but with an easier to read url.

**With the following code I tried to achieve my goal:**

**Functions.php:**

```
/**
 * For rewriting URLS on werkvorm
 */

add_action('init', function(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^werkvorm/([^/]+)([/]?)(.*)',
    'index.php?pagename=werkvorm&item=$matches[1]',
    'top'
    );
});

/**
 * Retrieve the data from the get parameter for werkvorm page
 */

add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'werkvorm';
    $vars[] = 'item';
    return $vars;
});
```

**On the werkvorm page i can use:**

```
$test = get_query_var( 'item' ); // to retrieve the data
```

Now when I use the url: `localhost/mysite/werkvorm/test`
I'm getting a 404. However when I use `localhost/mysite/werkvorm/?item=test` it works fine only the url is not changed. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Does changing the permalink structure to 'post name' not do the trick? (admin->settings->permalinks)

Comment: @Dan. Lol yup that was it. Thanks, i'm not so into Wordpress so i didn't know really.

Comment: No worries haha. Depending on your URL structure requirements, you may have to write some code. But the post name structure setting does the trick here

Comment: @Dan. Yeah, luckily I'm familiar with the rest of the required code haha but thanks for your help it saved me a lot of time. I can accept it as the answer below if you need any points.

Comment: I don't see why not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Permalink Structure to 'Post Name' in admin->settings->permalinks.

Depending on your URL structure requirements, you may have to write some code. But the post name structure setting will do the trick here.